# How do I write two lists to a dat file using pickle?

Tags: list, python-2.7, pickle

I'm pretty sure my format is wrong and that I'm not actually writing anything to this file. I'm trying to write `aList` and `bList` to `aFile`.

```
aList = ['useless', 'info']
bList = [1000,5000]

with open('aFile.dat', 'w') as f:
    pickle.dump('aFile.dat', f)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a dict with keys aList and bList and save it to the aFile like this:

```
import pickle

aList = ['useless', 'info']
bList = [1000,5000]

aFile=open('aFile.dat', 'w')
aFile.write(pickle.dumps({"aList":aList,"bList":bList}))
aFile.close()
```

If you wold like to append information you could do something more elaborated like this:

```
import pickle


def extract_dict(filename):
    try:
        oldInfoFile=open(filename, 'r')
    except:
        print "File could not be opened"
        return {}
    oldInfo=oldInfoFile.read()
    oldInfoFile.close()
    try:
        oldDict=pickle.loads(oldInfo)
    except AttributeError:
        print "Non valid Pickle format"
        return {}
    return oldDict

def append_dict(filename,more_info_dict):
    myDict=extract_dict(filename)
    myDict.update(more_info_dict)
    aFile=open(filename, 'w')
    aFile.write(pickle.dumps(myDict))
    aFile.close()


#Testing what we have in aFile.dat
print(extract_dict("aFile.dat"))

aList = ['useless', 'info']
bList = [1000,5000]
first_info={"aList":aList,"bList":bList}

#Adding data to aFile.dat
append_dict("aFile.dat",first_info)

#Verifying data was written to aFile.dat
print(extract_dict("aFile.dat"))

second_info={"aList2":aList,"bList2":bList}

#Writting more data    
append_dict("aFile.dat",second_info)

#Verifying new data was written to aFile.dat
print(extract_dict("aFile.dat"))
```

Comment: I like this. If I want to append it after I write it I just replace the 'w' with an 'a', correct?

Comment: Also, does this format make aFile a printable merged list? It's not important if it does, I'm just curious.

Comment: You could use 'a' to append more information to the file. However, by doing this, you won't be able to read the whole information. On the other hand, you could read the information you store at aFile.dat; add the new information and overwrite the information

Comment: I hope the additional code is what you were looking for

Comment: It probably is. I don't really understand how the first half, where you are defining everything, works yet so I don't feel comfortable using it. Though I was able to plug real data into your solution and it worked wonderfully. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, after a little trial and error I was able to modify your code with my data. After running this a couple of times in my program, I noticed it was overwriting the old data. Isn't appending supposed to only add to the existing data?

Comment: You are right @KirkStevenson What we are doing is reading the file and extracting the dictionary. Then we append the new dictionary to the one we have read and finally, we overwriting the file. I hope the code was not so complicated to understand.

Comment: Is there a way to write more than two files at the same time? I tried writing three and received `TypeError: dumps() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)`

Comment: Yes @KirkStevenson, what you have to do is to modify function "append_dict" to receive either a tuple or a list of dictionaries and use a loop to get every dictionary.